# Building SQL with foreach

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, firebird

I have this code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach(Int_String partner in partneri)
    {
        double danaBezProdaje = (DateTime.Today - Komercijalno.Partner.PoslednjaKupovina(partner._int)).TotalDays;
        if (danaBezProdaje > 31 && danaBezProdaje < 1100)
        {
            NeaktivniPartner np = new NeaktivniPartner();
            np.ppid = partner._int;
            np.naziv = partner._string;
            np.danaBezKupovine = danaBezProdaje;
            neaktivniPartneri.Add(np);
        }
    }
    dataGridView1.DataSource = M.List.ConvertToDataTable(neaktivniPartneri);
}
```

So in here i have `List<Int_String> partneri` which contains 5k rows. For each of it i run `Komercijalno.Partner.PoslednjaKupovina(partner._int)` which contains SQL statement which looks like this:

```
public static DateTime PoslednjaKupovina(int ppid)        
{
    using (FbConnection con = new FbConnection(M.Baza.connectionKomercijalno2018))
    {
        con.Open();
        using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand("SELECT DATUM FROM DOKUMENT WHERE PPID = @PPID ORDER BY DATUM DESC", con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPID", ppid);

            FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            if (dr.Read())
                return Convert.ToDateTime(dr[0]);
            else
                return new DateTime(1, 1, 1);
        }
    }
}
```

So SQL statement is executed 5k times which is way too slow.

So how could i pass my `List<Int_String>` or just array of ints to sql command so there i execute one time (inside foreach or how else) and return `dataAdapter` so i execute SQL only once.

DataAdapter returned should look like this:

```
| ppid     | datum    |
```

So let's say i have Table `PARTNER` (from which i populate List `partneri` with `SELECT PPID, NAZIV FROM PARTNER`) with this data in it:

```
| PPID    | NAZIV    |
| 1       | name001  |
| 2       | name002  |
| 3       | name003  |
| 4       | name004  |
```

And let's say my DOKUMENT table has this data:

```
| ID      | PPID    | DATE       |
| 1       | 2       | 12.03.2018 |
| 2       | 3       | 12.03.2018 |
| 3       | 2       | 05.03.2018 |
| 4       | 2       | 03.04.2018 |
| 5       | 1       | 26.03.2018 |
| 6       | 4       | 21.02.2018 |
| 7       | 4       | 06.05.2018 |
```

And output i want is:

```
| PPID    | DATE       |
| 1       | 26.03.2018 |
| 2       | 03.04.2018 |
| 3       | 12.03.2018 |
| 4       | 06.05.2018 |
```

Comment: Join that `ids` by `,` and use `in` in your where clause.

Comment: How should i pass it to command?

Comment: Not a good method  @Aria. The parameter string may get an error at the limit and a bad performance this way..

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag, I thought the limitation is more than `5k` , but I don't know the limitation exactly, but it can be separates block of `in` ?

Comment: @AleksaRistic Where do you fill the 'partneri' data ? If you get data on DB , why use join DOKUMENT table ?  if your answer is no , my solution is, Use the 'bulk insert' method to insert the ids data into the session temp table and join it with the document table. This is much faster

Comment: @HüseyinBurakKaradag i populate `partneri` at start of my program with background worker which `SELECT * FROM PARTNER` which is in same database file as `DOKUMENT`

Comment: @AleksaRistic, then `join` them like `select * from PARTNER JOIN DOKUMENT ON PARTNER ._int = DOKUMENT.PPID`

Comment: @Aria problem is that my function `PoslednjaKupovina` returns only latest date (first row). So when i join tables i will get about 10k (500k total) rows for each partner but i only need one of each and that one's date need to be closest to today.

Comment: @AleksaRistic, Yes if you join them you will get many rows in this case you should change your cod, iterates that rows each of row is equal to `PoslednjaKupovina` running , in the other words you get `5k` rows in one shoot instead of running `PoslednjaKupovina` 5k times.

Comment: Please post the DDL of relevant tables, sample data and expected result. I agree with Aria that using a join will be a lot better than executing individual selects (the so-called N+1 problem).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I have updated question with example database data and expected result. What does DDL mean?

Comment: DDL = Data Definition Language, so the create table statements, etc.

Comment: `select ppid, max(datum) from dokument group by ppid` ? Can there be values in DOKUMENT.PPID that are missed from PARTNER.PPID ??? If that is normal FOREIGN KEY then there won't be any. Or, to address Aleksa's later wish about days counter instead of dates, `select ppid, current_date - cast(max(datum) as date) from dokument group by ppid`  according to http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-datetimeops

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace all your logic with a single query that does:

```
select d.ppid, max(d.datum)
from partner p
inner join dokument d
    on d.ppid = p.ppid
group by d.ppid
```

You may need to add a `where`-clause with additional conditions to select which partners you want to have.

Comment: One more thing, instead of `max(d.datum)` i want to be `(DateTime.Today - max(d.datum)).TotalDays. How i can accomplish that inside query

Comment: @AleksaRistic You should consider leaving that in your C# code, but otherwise consider wrapping the select with another one, eg something like `select ppid, datediff(day, datum, current_date) datedifference from (<select from my answer>) a`

Comment: why nested selects? can not he put this subtraction directly into top-level select? And, perhaps, I would send `DateTime.Today` as a parameter from client. So that the server would treat it as constant, and because local datetimes can be different on client computer vs server computer

Comment: And perhaps in this specific case I would not use `DateDiff` but directly use `DATE - DATE` subtraction, typecasting `datum` column to the type if needed. http://www.firebirdtest.com/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-datatypes-datetime.html#fblangref25-datatypes-datetimeops

Comment: Can there be values in `DOKUMENT.PPID` that are missed from `PARTNER.PPID` ??? If that is normal FK then I guess this query should be stripped of references `PARTNER` table altogether! You just do not need it, you can aggregate on `DOKUMENT` table alone with no any join at all.

Comment: @Arioch'The i get the point but i need joining because i will not always want all PPID but maybe only `PPID 1, 11 and 68`

Comment: @AleksaRistic but I think your `PARTNER` table contains ALL the partners, not only `1,11,68` pre-selected to fetch, doesn't it ? and please, show table declarations (DDL, SCHEMA, create table statement - here it all means the same), because no one knows what type your DATUM column has, what are SQL-level relations between those two tables (are them FK or not), what are other constraints, etc

Comment: It also contains column `VIP` and only `1, 11 and 68 have VIP = 1` so when i want to check date for VIP guys i need to filter it

Comment: Mark Rottenveel's answer is working with addition of `datediff`

Comment: if the list of partners to check is always/mostly short, you can just pass it to the query. `select ppid, current_date - cast(max(datum) as date) from dokument group where ppid in (1,11,68) by ppid` or see that another question that I linked. Or you may modify Mark's answer with `....inner join dokument d on d.ppid = p.ppid and p.VIP=1`. Frankly, in Mark's query it would be more consistent to swap PARTNER and DOKUMENT tables. Not that it would change how the server sees it, but from human standpoint it is D which is primary data source and P is only used for secondary checks(filtering)

Comment: @AleksaRistic overall in this answer's comments you added two points, that are missed form the question itself. That you need days count rather than dates, and - important one - that your actual filtering is not some arbitrary, random list of IDs but the REAL criterion is `PARTNER.VIP=1`. You omitted the crucial information - what you do really want - from the question, and you was getting answers poorly tuned to your REAL problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377 /// Your points should be listed in the Question itself, not comments!!! Comments are noisy, hard to find there.

Comment: @Arioch'The I used nested select because I find it more readable, and I recall having issues with doing something like that with aggregate functions, but I can't recall if it was with Firebird or another database system.

Answer (score 0):

Making it as an answer, for there is already very many comments below the question, so it would just be lost in the noise there.

> So how could i pass my List or just array of ints to sql command so there i execute one time

That question was discussed here: [Filter sql based on C# List instead of a filter table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997516)

Depending upon how typical(frequent) is the query and how large is the data there are few ways.

- Global Temporary Tables
- Imitation of GTT using `UNION ALL` and several `select {constants} from RDB$database`
- Flattening the list into one long string of special format and using reversed `LIKE` matching.

PS. For your specific task Mark's answer is definitely much better: you do not have to fetch lot of data from the server only to pass it back in another query. I just wanted to link a question, related to a part of this one, that was already answered.