# SQL Query runs too slow

Tags: sql, firebird

I have this command

```
using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand(@"SELECT MIN(STAVKA.TREN_STANJE) FROM STAVKA RIGHT OUTER JOIN DOKUMENT ON STAVKA.VRDOK = DOKUMENT.VRDOK AND STAVKA.BRDOK = DOKUMENT.BRDOK WHERE(STAVKA.MAGACINID = @MID) AND(STAVKA.ROBAID = @RID) AND(DOKUMENT.FLAG < 2)", con))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MID", magacinId);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@RID", FbDbType.Integer);

    foreach(Int_Double stavka in stavkePocetnogStanjaSaKolicinama)
    {
        cmd.Parameters["@RID"].Value = stavka._int;

        using (FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {

            if (dr.Read())
            {
                double v = (dr[0] is DBNull) ? 0 : Convert.ToDouble(dr[0]);
                double t = stavka._double;
                if (smanjuj && !povecavaj)
                {
                    if (v >= 0)
                        stavka._double -= v;
                }
                else if (smanjuj && povecavaj)
                    stavka._double -= v;
                else if (!smanjuj && povecavaj)
                {
                    if (v < 0)
                        stavka._double -= v;
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Doslo je do greske! - SvediPocetnoStanjeNaMinimum");
                    return;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Where the SQL statement is:

```
SELECT MIN(STAVKA.TREN_STANJE) 
  FROM STAVKA 
  RIGHT OUTER JOIN DOKUMENT 
    ON STAVKA.VRDOK = DOKUMENT.VRDOK AND STAVKA.BRDOK = DOKUMENT.BRDOK 
  WHERE (STAVKA.MAGACINID = @MID) 
    AND (STAVKA.ROBAID = @RID) 
    AND (DOKUMENT.FLAG < 2)
```

Problem is that `using (FbDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())` takes about 3-4 seconds to run which would be okay if there are few times to run it but there is around 4k times needed to run so that is 16k seconds (4hrs)

How does these two table works is:

I have one document (`DOKUMENT`) which is one row and it has multiple items (`STAVKA`) which are connected to `DOKUMENT` (have document type (`VRDOK`) and document number (`BRDOK`)).

Now for each item (`STAVKA.ROBAID`) i select (`STAVKA.TREN_STANJE`) but `DOCUMENT.FLAG` which contains that `STAVKA` must have `flag < 2`

Example:

```
STAVKA TABLE
STAVKAID     | VRDOK    | BRDOK    | TREN_STANJE    | ROBAID  |
1            | 1        | 10       | 6              | 3       |
2            | 1        | 14       | 12             | 3       |
3            | 1        | 18       | 3              | 3       |
4            | 1        | 21       | 8              | 3       |
5            | 1        | 23       | 7              | 3       |


DOKUMENT TABLE
VRDOK    | BRDOK    | FLAG
1        | 10       | 1
1        | 14       | 3
1        | 18       | 1
1        | 21       | 1
1        | 23       | 4
```

So when i run SQL statement it need to select `MIN(TREN_STANJE)` from `STAVKA` WHERE `ROBAID = @RID (3 in this case)` BUT `FLAG` of that document (as you can see same columns in `DOKUMENT` and `STAVKA`) must be `< 2`

How could i speed this up?

Structure of `STAVKA` table is:

```
CREATE TABLE "STAVKA" 
(
  "STAVKAID"     INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "VRDOK"    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "BRDOK"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "MAGACINID"    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "ROBAID"   INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "VRSTA"    SMALLINT,
  "NAZIV"    VARCHAR(50),
  "NABCENSAPOR"  NUMERIC(15,4),
  "FAKTURNACENA"     NUMERIC(15,4),
  "NABCENABT"    DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "TROSKOVI"     NUMERIC(15,4),
  "NABAVNACENA"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "PRODCENABP"   NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "KOREKCIJA"    DOUBLE PRECISION,
  "PRODAJNACENA"     NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "DEVIZNACENA"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "DEVPRODCENA"  NUMERIC(15,4),
  "KOLICINA"     NUMERIC(15,3) NOT NULL,
  "NIVKOL"   NUMERIC(15,3) NOT NULL,
  "TARIFAID"     VARCHAR(3),
  "IMAPOREZ"     SMALLINT,
  "POREZ"    NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "RABAT"    NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "MARZA"    NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "TAKSA"    NUMERIC(15,4),
  "AKCIZA"   NUMERIC(15,2),
  "PROSNAB"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "PRECENA"  NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "PRENAB"   NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "PROSPROD"     NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "MTID"     VARCHAR(10),
  "PT"   CHAR(1) NOT NULL,
  "ZVEZDICA"     VARCHAR(6),
  "TREN_STANJE"  NUMERIC(15,3),
  "POREZ_ULAZ"   NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "SDATUM"   DATE,
  "DEVNABCENA"   NUMERIC(15,4),
  "POREZ_IZ"     NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "X4"   NUMERIC(15,3),
  "Y4"   NUMERIC(15,3),
  "Z4"   NUMERIC(15,3),
  "CENAPOAJM"    NUMERIC(15,2),
  "KGID"     INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT "STAVKAPRIMARYKEY" PRIMARY KEY ("STAVKAID")
);
```

Structure of `DOKUMENT` is:

```
CREATE TABLE "DOKUMENT" 
(
  "VRDOK"    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "BRDOK"    INTEGER NOT NULL,
  "INTBROJ"  VARCHAR(15),
  "KODDOK"   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "FLAG"     SMALLINT,
  "DATUM"    DATE NOT NULL,
  "LINKED"   VARCHAR(10),
  "MAGACINID"    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "PPID"     INTEGER,
  "FAKTDOBIZV"   VARCHAR(15),
  "PLACEN"   SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "DATROKA"  DATE,
  "NUID"     SMALLINT,
  "NRID"     SMALLINT,
  "VALUTA"   VARCHAR(3) NOT NULL,
  "KURS"     NUMERIC(15,4) NOT NULL,
  "ZAPID"    SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "UPLACENO"     NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "TROSKOVI"     NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "DUGUJE"   NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "POTRAZUJE"    NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "POPUST"   NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "RAZLIKA"  NUMERIC(15,2),
  "DODPOREZ"     NUMERIC(15,2),
  "POREZ"    NUMERIC(15,2),
  "PRODVREDBP"   NUMERIC(15,2) NOT NULL,
  "KUPAC"    VARCHAR(50),
  "OPISUPL"  VARCHAR(30),
  "VRDOKIN"  SMALLINT,
  "BRDOKIN"  INTEGER,
  "VRDOKOUT"     SMALLINT,
  "BRDOKOUT"     INTEGER,
  "MAGID"    SMALLINT,
  "POPUST1DANA"  INTEGER,
  "POPUST1PROCENAT"  NUMERIC(15,2),
  "POPUST2DANA"  INTEGER,
  "POPUST2PROCENAT"  NUMERIC(15,2),
  "POPUST3DANA"  INTEGER,
  "POZNABROJ"    CHAR(2),
  "POPUST3PROCENAT"  NUMERIC(15,2),
  "KONTRBROJ"    CHAR(2),
  "MTID"     VARCHAR(10),
  "REFID"    SMALLINT,
  "STATUS"   SMALLINT,
  "PPO"  SMALLINT,
  "PRENETI_POREZ"    NUMERIC(15,2),
  "AKVRDOK"  SMALLINT,
  "AKBRDOK"  INTEGER,
  "ALIASIZ"  SMALLINT,
  "ALIASU"   SMALLINT,
  "PREVOZROBE"   SMALLINT,
  "DATUM_PDV"    DATE,
  "NDID"     SMALLINT,
  "NABVREDNOST"  NUMERIC(15,2),
  "SAT_START"    VARCHAR(8),
  "SAT_END"  VARCHAR(8),
  "KNJIZNAOZ"    NUMERIC(15,2),
  "POVRATNICE"   NUMERIC(15,2),
  "SINHRO"   SMALLINT,
  "STORNO"   NUMERIC(15,2),
  "SMENAID"  SMALLINT NOT NULL,
  "POR_ODB"  NUMERIC(15,2),
CONSTRAINT "DOKUMENTPRIMARYKEY" PRIMARY KEY ("VRDOK", "BRDOK")
);
```

Comment: You don't even have any parameters in that SQL string. Is this really the exact code you are using?

Comment: Without knowing the exact table structure (e.g. what data types are the columns, how many rows are in each table) we can merely *guess* why the query is slow.

Comment: Additionally, `smanjuj` and `povecavaj` are difficult to understand variable names, and if we don't know what they mean we cannot semantically understand your code and help optimize it.

Comment: Based on what it looks like you are doing, I might try creating a temp table of `stavka._int` and do a single query by joining on it instead of a query execution for each.

Comment: What @Crowcoder mentioned is exactly the problem right now. It *looks like* you are doing something, but I suspect a so-called [XY problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) and we need quite some more information to know what you are actually trying to achieve. That's where the slow performance of the query likely comes from - a somewhat wrong approach to the problem. We only see the approach, but we need to see the problem to be able to sufficiently help you.

Comment: If you run the query directly against the database (using https://www.firebirdsql.org/en/third-party-tools/) how long does it take?

Comment: (short note: database access layer classes should probably not show message boxes)

Comment: @Crowcoder For testing purpose i changed parameters into manually written but i have changed it back on how it should been

Comment: @ThomasFlinkow `smanjuj` and `povecavaj` are bools but they do not make any problem since when i debug line with `using(FbDataReader.....` takes 3 sec not `if/else` with those variables

Comment: @mjwills I have tried that with manually inserting parameters so it runs only once and it takes 3-4 sec

Comment: If it takes 3-4 seconds to run directly against the DB (without C#) then this isn't a C# question. It is purely a Firebird question.

Comment: `RIGHT OUTER JOIN DOKUMENT ... WHERE ... AND (DOKUMENT.FLAG < 2)` - you do not need RIGHT JOIN here since you explicitly remove NULL values, hence use usual JOIN (aka INNER JOIN)

Comment: You should create a single query instead of N+1, that is executing 1 query and then executing N queries based on the results. This is essentially a duplicate of your earlier question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50363866/building-sql-with-foreach

Comment: BTW, who is native English speaker? Why inner and outer joins are called inner and outer ?

Comment: @Arioch'The I suggest you ask a question tagged with SQL for that.

Answer (score 1):

This query is first reading the `DOKUMENT` table, and then reading the `STAVKA` table.

If the **selectivity** of the filter criteria `DOKUMENT.FLAG < 2` is good, then an index should make it fast. A good selectivity is when the filtered rows are less than 5% of the table, ideally less than 0.5% of the rows of the table. For a good selectivity I would make sure I have the following index created:

```
create index ix1_document on DOKUMENT (FLAG);
```

Then, it's reading the table `STAVKA`. I would assume that table already has an index by `VRDOK`/`BRDOK`, since it's probably a foreign key. However, this is not enough to make it faster. You need to include `MAGACINID`, `ROBAID`, and `TREN_STANJE` in the index:

```
create index ix1_stavka (VRDOK, BRDOK, MAGACINID, ROBAID, TREN_STANJE);
```

This extra index will increase performance.

Now, if you already have these indexes, then there isn't much more you can do at the SQL optimization level.

The next option is to use **caching**. If you are running the query 4000 times, maybe you could run it once and keep the results in memory for the next 60 seconds. All subsequent calls will show it from memory instead of running the query again... until those 60 seconds pass, and you consider the result "stale".

Another option is to use in-memory database option, if available on Firebird, but I'm not sure about this.