# How can I bind a Python list as a parameter in a custom query in SQLAlchemy and Firebird?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, firebird

### Environment

I am using Firebird database with SQLAlchemy as ORM wrapper.

### Backgound

I know that by using `in_` it is possible to pass the `sales_id` list in `IN` clause and get the result.

I have a use case where I must use **textual sql**.

### Question

Here is my snippet,

```
conn.execute('select * from sellers where salesid in (:sales_id)', sales_id=[1, 2, 3] ).fetchall()
```

This always throws `token unknown error`

All I need is to pass the list of `sales_id` (`[1, 2, 3]`) to bind parameter (`:sales_id`) and get the result set.

Comment: Firebird itself doesn't support passing arrays or lists to a parameter in an IN-predicate, it only supports discrete values here. Which driver are you using, and does it provide special support for this?

Comment: I am using DP-API driver, which I think is the default. As @Ilja Everilä `bindparam` is the method as of now. Thanks, Mark for your effort.

Comment: DB-API is the Python specification for drivers, not a driver itself. Are you using FDB or pyfirebirdsql as your driver?

Comment: Sorry my bad, I am using FDB

Comment: Sometimes it may make sense to reverse the IN-condition and use SQL `CONTAINING` instead, if your list can grow truly long. See alternative approach at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997801/976391

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If using a DB-API driver that does not provide special handling of tuples and lists for producing expressions for row constructors and `IN` predicates, you can use the somewhat new feature "expanding" provided by [`bindparam`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/sqlelement.html#sqlalchemy.sql.expression.bindparam):

```
stmt = text('select * from sellers where salesid in :sales_id') 
stmt = stmt.bindparams(bindparam('sales_id', expanding=True))

conn.execute(stmt, sales_id=[1, 2, 3]).fetchall()
```

This will replace the placeholder `sales_id` on a per query basis by required placeholders to accommodate the sequence used as the parameter.

Comment: `conn.execute(stmt, sales_id=[1, 2, 3]).fetchall()` returns `TypeError: get_bind() got an unexpected keyword argument 'sales_id'`. By changing to `conn.execute(stmt, {'sales_id': [1, 2, 3]} ).fetchall()`, I am able to get what I needed. Thanks Ilja Everilä

Comment: What `conn` is? At least `Engine.execute()` accepts keyword arguments as arguments to query.

Comment: As does [`Connection.execute()`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/connections.html#sqlalchemy.engine.Connection.execute).

Comment: `conn` is the connection object