# SQL Selecting from very long list of values

Tags: java, sql, spring-data-jpa, firebird, jaybird

I need to select based on a big list:

```sql
SELECT ... FROM tb WHERE tb.cl IN (?, ?, ?, ..................many)
```

I can't do it this way because the driver implementation ([Jaybird](https://firebirdsql.org/en/jdbc-driver/#jaybird3)) limits the query to 1500 parameters max, also I can't select/load all and filter inside the app because there's not enough memory.

What should I do?

### Extra info

I'm using Spring Boot with Hibernate and JPA Repositories, so if could be done in JPQL or using some other environment-related technique it would fit nicer.

I will actually use a `...WHERE tb.cl NOT IN...`, if it makes any difference.
It's kinda like an EDI, I'm connecting two distinct databases, so using a nested select isn't an option.

Comment: Why do you want to pass 1,500 values to a `select`?  If it is the result of another `select`, then you can do all the work directly in SQL.  If there is another source, then create a table with the values.

Comment: I'm making an EDI app for another two, so I'm actually talking about two databases (not even same server tech, one is Firebird and other MySQL)

Comment: Jaybird itself doesn't limit the number of items in the IN-list (nor the number of parameters), that are implementation limits of Firebird itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter sql based on C# List instead of a filter table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43997516/filter-sql-based-on-c-sharp-list-instead-of-a-filter-table)

Comment: `IN` in Firebird is converted into `X=A OR X=B or X=C or ....` which is quite slow and resources-consuming on long lists. It is not recommended to use long IN-lists in Firebird. See 3 alternative approaches at https://stackoverflow.com/a/43997801/976391 Additionally, if your list is populated from some tree - usually correct query would need only parent IDs without all their children IDs

Comment: FYI: Firebird 5.0 will raise the `IN`-limit from 1500 to 65535 items (though you might hit other limits if all those items are parameters), and also has some other optimizations to improve the performance of such an `IN`, though those optimizations are more likely to work for literal values than for parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One alternative is to use a **temporary table** and do as many inserts as you need into that table. After that you can use a:

```
Select .. from tb where tb.cl in (select cl from myTempTable)
```

and then do a  truncate on the temporary table or a drop. As far as I know, all the leading relational databases set a limit in the IN clause if you are using parameters.
On the other hand, using a temp table will do the trick.

Comment: Firebird supports [global temporary tables](https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fblangref25-en/html/fblangref25-ddl-tbl.html#fblangref25-ddl-tbl-gtt). You only need to define a global temporary table once, and the content is only visible to the current transaction or the current connection depending on the definition (`on commit delete rows` vs `on commit preserve rows`), so there is no need to delete or truncate yourself.

Comment: it would still not be best approach to use IN even against another table. Tables are to be `JOIN`ed instead.

Comment: @Arioch'The why is that?

Comment: @LucasNoetzold I already told above in the comments to the question. That just does not scale up well in Groton/Interbase/Firebird lineage.